# Eclipse - Basic Array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, average

INSTRUCTION:
Create a regular class which one static method which can
process a one-dimensional array:
• method which accepts a one-dimensional array and returns the
average value of the elements.

```
package com.array; //THIS IS A REGULAR CLASS

public class oneDimensional
{
int[] x = {1,2,3,4,5};

static void printElements(int[] x)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
}

int getSum(int[] x)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int elements : x)
    {
        sum = (sum + elements)/x.length;
    }
    return sum;
}}



package com.array; //MAIN METHOD
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] Elements = {1,2,3,4,5};
        oneDimensional onedime = new oneDimensional();  
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Elements));
        int sum = onedime.getSum(Elements);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

}

I don't know why the output (Average) is 1. It should be 3, not 1.

Comment: That's not how you compute an average. First you sum all the elements, then, finally, you divide the result by the length. That's not what your code is doing. Also, why do you name `getSum()` a method that computes an average?

Answer (score 2):

You are using integer division, so you're missing the non-whole part of each division.

Generally speaking, an average of a series of `int`s doesn't need to be an `int` itself. You should use `double`s instead:

```
double getAvergage(int[] x) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int element : x) {
        sum += element;
    }
    return sum / x.length;
}
```